# Reading/writing to a file a couple of folders up

Tags: c, debugging

I am trying to create some code where a user inputs the name of a file, and the program then travels a couple of folders up, and then into a separate folder called "Files", finds the file, and echoes it.

```
void readfile() {
    FILE *file;
    int c;
    char str[30] = "..\\..\\Files";
    char temp[30];
    printf("Please enter the name of the file\n");
    fgets(temp, sizeof (temp), stdin);
    strcat(str, temp);
    file = fopen(str, "r");
    if (file) {
        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
            putchar(c);
        fclose(file);
    } else {
        printf("File does not exist!");
    }
    //printf(string);
    fclose(file);
}
```

However, when it tries to open up a file, the program crashes in Netbeans, but it returns the "File does not exist" error in CLion. I am very confused and I cannot pinpoint the problem.

Comment: You must remove the newline that `fgets` probably includes at the end of `temp`. Please [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221).

Comment: 1) don't bean-count.  [256], say, for temp.  2) strcpy the path to temp, then strcat the name to it. 3) printf() out the full path+ filename spec so you know it's right.

Comment: ...and for `str` too, you already used up half its niggardly length which you `strcat` to. Even better when developing use strings of 1000 length and tone them down later.

Comment: Oh.. and you need another '\\', something you would have seen if you had printed out the whole file spec.

Comment: We are off topic here: give the absolute program path. I am sure this has been asked many times. Where is the working folder?

Comment: @MartinJames - the most egregious error of them all :)

Comment: The working folder is on a Linux server, and I am using a remote build to a Linux workstation to run it, using Putty to check if the files are created. But I am not using remote build on the CLion project where I test the code. It crashes on the Linux remote run and not the local CLion run, which really confuses me.

Comment: this is the source of your problem: `strcat(str, temp);`  because `str` is already over 1/2 full and `temp` is (possibly) another 30 characters.  so 16+30 => 46

Comment: there are several different reasons a call to `fopen()` could fail.  this line: `printf("File does not exist!");` has two problems 1) it might not be the correct reason 2) error messages are to be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Suggest using: `perror( "fopen failed" );`   Then it will output to `stderr` and will include a message saying why the OS thinks the call failed.

Comment: the code calls: `fclose( file );`  twice in the same execution path.  This is an error, especially if the call to `fopen() failed.